# How to produce nested json from postgresql query and wrap it with row count information?

Tags: json, postgresql

With this simple relation schema:

```
CREATE TABLE district (
    id  SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    loc TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE person (
    id          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name        TEXT,
    district_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES district(id)
);
```

I need a query for API pagination purpose that produce something like this:

```
{
    "total_rows": 37,
    "list": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Rebecca Jaskolski",
            "district": {
                "id": 3,
                "loc": "Albastad"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Newton Weissnat",
            "district": {
                "id": 4,
                "loc": "West Myronchester"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My query for now to produce JSON output with that shape above is like this:

```
SELECT row_to_json(a) FROM (
    SELECT (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM person
    ) AS total_rows, (
        SELECT json_agg(row_to_json(t)) AS persons FROM (
            SELECT person.id, person.name, (
                SELECT row_to_json(d) AS district FROM (
                    SELECT district.id, district.loc FROM district where district.id = person.district_id
                ) d
            ) FROM
        ) t
    ) AS list
) a;
```

As you can see, the query above is doing two query, `COUNT` and the actual query. It can be inefficient if the database is growing large right?

So, is there any better way?

Comment: u can use `select n_live_tup from pg_stat_all_tables where relname` stats If you don't mind approximate statistics, alse if you have serial, getting current value is good approximation (if you dont massively delete data) of course

Comment: also if you select all rows anyway, you better `count(1) over ()` to get the number, instead of separate `count(*)` in subselect

Comment: What PG version are you using

Comment: @JoeLove version 9.6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `json_build_object()`. In my opinion this is the easiest and most flexible way of building nested json structures.

```
select json_build_object(
    'total_rows', count(*), 
    'list', json_agg(person)) as persons
from (
    select json_build_object(
        'id', p.id, 
        'name', name, 
        'district', json_build_object('id', d.id, 'loc', d.loc)) person
    from person p
    join district d on d.id = p.district_id
    ) s
```

[Test it here.](http://rextester.com/ETA22480).